# API to data for react/redux js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, redux

I have the following API :

```
{
  list_A: [ ],
  list_B: [ ],
  list_C: {},
}
```

How can I map the data to display the category from Redux state : list_A, list_B, list_C, and not the dates inside.

I used `JSON.parse(listType)` but it didn't work

```
  const listType = useSelector((state) => state.orderReducer);
  {listType.map((type) => console.log(type))}
```

Result:
**ERROR
listType.map is not a function
TypeError: listType.map is not a function**

Thank you

Comment: Did you log `listType`? What is the actual value? Is it actually an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const categories = {
  list_A: [],
  list_B: [],
  list_C: {},
}
console.log(Object.keys(categories))
```